# Rails has many and belongs to between two times with same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wondering how to do something so If someone knows I will be glad to hear. I have the following models

```
User
Usertype
Course
```

I have two types of users - student and teacher. 
What I want to have is two tables

```
CourseTeacher - course_id, teacher_id 
CourseStudent - course_id, student_id
```

My User model has `usertype_id` column. So I am wondering how to use `has_many_and_belongs_to` in that case because everything depends on `usertype_id` column in User model.

Answer (score 1):

I think class inheritance is a cleaner way to model your domain logic:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Student < User
end

class Teacher < User
end
```

Then the table would have an `id` and `type` column, greatly simplifying what you're trying to accomplish. Read the API docs to learn more: [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ability to refactor, you can try using this approach:

Instead of 2 tables create one:

```
class CoursesUsers
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the decide yourself logic inside the user model (It seems like polymorphic to me)